# YACC 7 rules never reduced 15 reduce/reduce conflicts

Tags: bison, yacc

I am trying to make a basic compiler parse and interpret a simple made up programming language. I have my context free grammar created, and have tried to implement it in YACC, but I keep getting '6 fules never reduced'. Here are my productions in the yacc file

```
%token BEGIN END INT INT_CONST STRING STRING_LIT TERM ID PRINT

%%


start : program
      ;

program: ID 'is' compound_statement
                    ; 

compound_statement: BEGIN statement_loop END; {;}
                    ;

statement_loop: statement statement_loop
                | statement
                ;

statement:      ID '=' expr ';'
                | ID'=' STRING_LIT ';'
                | PRINT value_loop ';'
                ;

value_loop:     value '.' value_loop
                | value
                ;

value:          STRING_LIT
                | expr
                ;

expr:           term_loop
                | '-' term_loop
                ;

term_loop:      term
                | term '+' term_loop
                | term '-' term_loop
                ;

term:           factor_loop
                ;

factor_loop:    factor_loop
                | factor '*' factor_loop
                | factor '/' factor_loop
                ;

declaration:    INT id_loop
                | STRING id_loop
                ;

id_loop:        ID
                | id_loop ','
                ;

factor:         INT_CONST
                | ID
                '(' expr ')'
                ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`factor_loop` has no non-recursive production, so it cannot ever produce anything. You probably meant the first production to be `factor_loop: factor`.

Since `factor_loop` can't produce anything, all of the productions which rely on `factor_loop` are also useless.

There are a number of other problems with that grammar, so other error messages  are likely.  I don't see anything which would cause reduce-reduce conflicts, which makes me wonder whether what you provided was the complete literal grammar file.

Some of the issues:

1. In `program`, `'is'` is not a valid single-character token.
2. There is a stray semicolon after the `END` in `compound_statement`.
3. `declaration` is not used anywhere.
4. `id_loop` produces an `ID` followed by any number of commas. So `a,,,,` is a valid `id_loop` but not `a, b, c`.
5. I'm pretty sure you are missing a `|` at the beginning if the third line of `factor`.
6. There is way too much right recursion. In some cases, this only produces excess parser stack usage, but it is particularly serious for arithmetic operators because it makes right-associative and they aren't.

   In particular, it parses `1 - 2 - 3` as `1 - (2 - 3)` instead of the correct `(1 - 2) - 3`
7. Unary minus has far too high a precedence. You will end up parsing `-2 + 6` as though it had been written `-(2 + 6)`, so the result will be -8 instead of 4.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful, thank you. I did not realize how much I was missing.  Where would appropriate places be to change right recursion to left recursion? Also, how would I go about changing the precedence of the unary minus operator?

Comment: @conor: 1. All of them imho. 2. Unary minus should apply to factors. Take a look at example expression cfgs.

Comment: To address the unary minus issue, would it be appropriate to add %left '-' '+' to the top of the yacc file?

Comment: @connor no. Your grammar is not ambiguous as far as I can see, so precedence declarations will have no effect. (Anyway, unary minus needs special handling with precedence declarations.)

Comment: So changing to left recursion will automatically solve it?

Comment: @connor it will fix the associativity of binary operators but you'll need to fix the grammar for unary minus.